# How to create a list from a list

Tags: python, list

How to get list of 'Health' and 'E.R. nurses' and its id numbers
for example:

```
books =
[
       ['Health', 18327],
       ['Health', 19438],
       ['Health', 12549],
       ['Health', 11662],
       ['E.R.nurses', 21458],
]
```

Output should be like this:

```
[
      ['Health',18327,19438,12549,11662],['E.R.nurses',21458]
]
```

I tried with :

```
output = [ [title, n] for title, n in books if....
```

but 'n' can have more numbers...so I have no idea :|
thank for any tips

Comment: why don't you use a dictionary instead? That seems to be more fitting

Comment: Right ! Thank you Mahrkeenerh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to use a dictionary, actually you can use a defaultdict:

```
books =[
       ['Health', 18327],
       ['Health', 19438],
       ['Health', 12549],
       ['Health', 11662],
       ['E.R.nurses', 21458],
]

from collections import defaultdict

x = defaultdict(list)

[x[key].append(val) for [key,val] in books]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code, the only difference is that it will turn your list into a dictionary, but it will separete as you want

Code:

```py
dic = {

}

books = [
    ['Health', 18327],
    ['Health', 19438],
    ['Health', 12549],
    ['Health', 11662],
    ['E.R.nurses', 21458],
]

for book in books:
    if book[0] not in dic.keys():
        dic[book[0]] = [book[1], ]

    else:
        dic[book[0]].append(book[1])

print(dic)
```

Comment: It works and it's easy to understand , thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following outputs the format you want:

```py
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter

books = [['Health', 18327], ['Health', 19438], ['Health', 12549], ['Health', 11662], ['E.R.nurses', 21458]]

output = [[k, *(lst[1] for lst in g)] for k, g in itertools.groupby(books, key=itemgetter(0))]

print(output)
# [['Health', 18327, 19438, 12549, 11662], ['E.R.nurses', 21458]]
```

This uses [generalized unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) (python 3.5+).

Also it assumes (to use `groupby`) that in the input, lists having `'health'` must be next to each other, lists having `'E.R.nurses'` must be next to each other, and so on. If your data is not like that, you can put `books.sort(key=itemgetter(0))` beforehand.

Comment: it doesn't always 'adjancent' , but thanks it's a good code to study